# .NET MassTransit - Cannot create only consumer

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azureservicebus, masstransit

Hi as phatboyg told me and states in his article, for azure functions you need to create a topic/subscription yourself. How do you feel about this? I tried to create a topic using the SDK however there are no topics set as I am used to from mass transit. (Isn't there somewhere a rule for the same setup as in mass transit?) Setting up a topic and subscription in some service for functions is also a problem, because from what I understand mass transit just can't set it up without a consumer. I don't know what to do with it anymore.

Thanks a lot in advance

I've tried to think of the best way - to create consumers from the application using the mass transit library. Founding with Azure Service Bus SDK. I'm trying to achieve handy functionality and also the same topic/subscription functionality as in mass transit. Thanks a lot

I tried this. However, the problem here is that this creates a subscription, but also a consumera if I understand it correctly, which does nothing, but logically it then thrashes.

```
cfg.SubscriptionEndpoint<OrderSubmited>("test-sub", e =>
{
  e.ConfigureConsumers(context);        
});
```

Then I did it like this. That works. But the topic/subscription setting is not the same and for example sending to the error queue is a problem.

```
 if (!adminClient.SubscriptionExistsAsync("OrderSubmited", "test-sub").GetAwaiter().GetResult().Value)
     adminClient.CreateSubscriptionAsync("OrderSubmited", "test-sub");
```

Working create topic with subscription without consumer.

**Edit:**

[Flow of services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbdZM.png)

Azure function configuration:

```
    services.AddMassTransitForAzureFunctions(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.AddConsumers(Assembly.Load("Messaging"));
    }, "ServiceBusConnection");
```

Service configuration:

```
    services.AddMassTransit(o =>
    {
        o.SetEndpointNameFormatter(formatter);

        o.AddConsumers(Assembly.Load("Messaging"));

        o.UsingAzureServiceBus(async (context, cfg) =>
        {
            cfg.Host("string");

            cfg.SubscriptionEndpoint<SomeChange>(formatter.Consumer<SomeChangeConsumer>(), e =>
            {
                e.ConfigureConsumer<SomeChangeConsumer>(context);
            });

            var adminClient = new ServiceBusAdministrationClient(conString, new DefaultAzureCredential());

            if (await !adminClient.TopicExistsAsync(Azurefunction))
                await adminClient.CreateTopicAsync(Azurefunction);
            if (await !adminClient.SubscriptionExistsAsyncAzurefunction, AzurefunctionSubs))
                await adminClient.CreateSubscriptionAsync(Azurefunction, AzurefunctionSubs);
        });
    });
```

Comment: @Sampath I deleted it because the discussion went a little off track. The thing is, the solution you posted is the same as mine. But the thing is that when I manually create a subscription like this, it works in mass transit in functions, but still if there is an exception, the consumer is called 10 times again. The only solution was to set maxdelivery to 1, but that doesn't seem ok to me.

Comment: @Sampath I don't think that's gonna solve my problem. Because it still happens that it runs 3 times. MassTransit has it default that when an exception occurs in the consumer, it immediately executes a publish fault message. So when I create it manually via adminclient, because I can't use mass transit for this, the consumer is triggered multiple times. And your idea I think just changes this repetition to 3 times. I added an edit and tried to explain it even better.

Comment: @Sampath I don't think we understand each other. But this is already a mass transit implementation, https://masstransit.io/documentation/concepts/exceptions#retry I understand that. So they're going to try it again and because it's in a transaction nothing will happen in case of a crash. But! When I have created my topic with subscription manually, in case of exception in consumer it runs 10 times without having this construct used there. And only after 10 attempts it crashes into the error queue.